# How to list last changed files in one directory

Tags: file, last-modified

if anyone hacks a site, then I would like to check which files are changed maybe in the last 24 hours in the directory htdocs, that means the files in the subdirectories form htdocs too. How to do this?

I will be happy for any suggestions,

Cheers
Nik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find {dir} -mtime -1 -print
```

will find files modified in the last 24 hours (-1 = 1 day)

If you're using [zsh](http://www.zsh.org), then you can do:

```
ls **/*(mh-24)
```

which shows you files modified in the last 24 hours (you can specify different params for minutes/hours etc. and whether you want modified/accessed etc.)